# ZipPackage Class vs Zipfile class

Tags: c#, .net, zip

I feel confused with these two classes, both of them seem used to create or extract zip files? Can anyone explain the difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ZipPackage Class` - Implements a derived subclass of the abstract Package base class—the ZipPackage class uses a ZIP archive as the container store. This class cannot be inherited.

`Zipfile Class` - Provides static methods for creating, extracting, and opening zip archives.

refer these links to get exact differences
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.packaging.zippackage.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfile.aspx

`ZipPackage Class` is used to handle packages, which uses the zip format for storage, but has special meta files included in the zip. A package is a zip, but all zip files aren't packages. You can only open a package using the Package class, not any zip file.

when you want just only the zip file I would prefer using zipFile class until I want my zip to be a package.

If you only want to zip your file and extract it use zipClass instead

Comment: Hi @Ajeet, thanks for your reply. I have read them already, but I still don't know when to use ZipPackge and when to use ZipFile, could you please help me?