# How do I move (or copy) a ZIPPackage to a new location

Tags: .net, zip

I'm an unclear whether a ZIPPackage is a file, a directory or something else.

My ZIPPackage lives in one folder and I want to programmatically copy it to a different folder.

What objects and methods should I use?

Answer (score 0):

The "physical bytes" are either a file (typically) or a stream (for example, if you dynamically read the package from a web server).

You can use standard System.IO (to read, write and copy the bytes) or (better) the .Net ZIPPackage class (which understands .Zip compression as well as ZIPPackage metadata).

Look here for more details: [ZipPackage Class vs Zipfile class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12889574/zippackage-class-vs-zipfile-class)

Comment: So I can copy the zip file to a new location with File.Copy, is that correct?